# Controlling a page loaded with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a page loaded in a div using `.load()`.

Now I have 2 problems:

1. How can I constrain the loaded page's size to its container?

   Or alternatively, how can I control the loaded pages size?
2. How can I affect the divs of the loaded page from the container page with js functions?

The container page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        #box {
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #box h2 {
            padding-left: 10px;
            line-height: 5px;
            font-size: 18px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .view-picker {
            height: 100px;
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 20px;
        }
        .view {
            position: fixed;
            background: #eee;
        }
        .active {
            background: #ddd;
        }
        .btn {
            background: #ccc;
        }
        .input-group label{
            margin-right: 30px;
        }
        @media(max-width:500px){
            .view-picker {
                font-size: 20px;
            }
        }
        @media(min-width:500px){
            .view-picker {
                font-size: 30px;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box"></div>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $("#box").load("page2.php");
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The loaded page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
        html, body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }
        .wrapper {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .one {
            position: fixed;
            width: 15%;
            z-index: 0;
        }
        .two {
            position: fixed;
            width: 85%;
            left: 15%;
            background: #ddd;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .three {
            width:32%;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        .view-picker {
            display: block;
        }
        .view {
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        form {
            padding: 25px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="one" id="view-picker-list">
        <a href="#" class="view-picker" value="avl"></a>
        <a href="#" class="view-picker" value="fnd"></a>
        <a href="#" class="view-picker" value="ock"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="two">
        <div class="view" id="avl">
            <h2>Page 1</h2>
        <div class="view" id="fnd">
            <h2>Page 2</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="view" id="ock">
            <h2>Page 3</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- show/hide functions -->
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $("#fnd").hide();
            $("#ock").hide();
            $("a[value='avl']").addClass("active");

            var showit = '';

            $(".view-picker").click(function(){
                showit = $(this).attr('value');
                $(".view:not(#" + showit + ")").slideUp("slow");
                $(".view-picker:not(this)").removeClass("active");
                $('#' + showit).slideDown("slow");
                $(this).addClass("active");
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you want set the width and height for the div as 100%

Comment: It is, but it ignores the container-div's dimensions and just spreads all over the page

Comment: Then please give us any relevant HTML (both for the container element and the element being loaded) and CSS so that we might replicate the problem

Comment: please post your code in code snippet

Comment: @vijay If you mean a Stack Snippet, that won't work since it's using ajax. The OP could post the code on something like [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/) which does allow for ajax, which could help matters.

Comment: You should be careful when using `style`s and `script`s with [`load()`, as the documentation notes](http://api.jquery.com/load/). Those styles will be applied to the parent document as well as the loaded document.

Comment: OK, the fix for the size issue was "position: fixed" in the loaded content. Any ideas for accessing the divs inside the loaded page with jquery? i.e. `$("#div-inside-load").html('hello');`